# Knockout data binding a concatenated array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

How would I data-bind a concatenated array of strings in Knockout? I want to do something like this:

```
<span data-bind='text: foreach person in persons person.name+","+person.age>
```

Obviously the syntax is wrong but is it possible to do something like the above without creating multiple spans for each person?

Comment: You can always use a computed that loops over the observableArray and concats a string together. However, generally speaking, when you start getting into the business of having computeds that observe arrays, you start having performance issues with mid to large data sets. 

Could you share why you want to do this? Is the only place in the html templates where you are foreach'ing over persons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use any kind of valid javascript in data-bind. so think is possible to do something like this:

**Option 1** - [See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FrankFuenmayor/rc1y16pr/)

Assuming a model like this:

```
var model = {
  people : ko.observableArray([
    {name: "Name1", age: 30},
    {name: "Name2", age: 31},
    {name: "Name3", age: 32},
  ])
}

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

We can do:

```
<span data-bind='text: people().map(function(p){return p.name + "," + p.age}).join(", ")'> </span>
```

**Option 2** - [See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FrankFuenmayor/fo722sc5/1/)

But is not a good practice to embed coplex inline javascript, I would recomend to create a computed property like this

```
var model = {
  people : ko.observableArray([
    {name: "Name1", age: 30},
    {name: "Name2", age: 31},
    {name: "Name3", age: 32},
  ]),
}

model.allPeople = ko.computed(function() {
    return model.people().map(function(p){return p.name + "," + p.age}).join(", ");
});

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

And the HTML:

```
<span data-bind='text: allPeople'> </span>
```